# Is this a bug in the official doc about function overloading?

Tags: solidity

From the [official doc](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/contracts.html#function-overloading):

> Overloaded functions are also present in the external interface. It is an error if two externally visible functions differ by their Solidity types but not by their external types.

Then followed by an example (I changed `B` by `uint`):

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.16 <0.7.0;

// This will not compile
contract A {
    function f(B _in) public pure returns (B out) {
        out = _in;
    }

    function f(address _in) public pure returns (address out) {
        out = _in;
    }
}
```

But i actually could compile the above code with no issue. Is this a bug in the doc or something?

```
$ truffle compile

Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling ./contracts/Test.sol
> Artifacts written to /.../solidity/study/Test/build/contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.6.4+commit.1dca32f3.Emscripten.clang
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have missed the explanation at the bottom of that example:

> Both `f` function overloads above end up accepting the `address` type for the ABI although they are considered different inside Solidity.

**Translation to English:**

While `B` and `address` are considered by the compiler as different types, for the ABI they are identical (`B` is essentially equivalent to `address`).

Once you change `B` to `uint`, that coding example will obviously compile because `uint` and `address` are treated as different types also in the ABI.